# How does real GDP take into account technological advancement?

Tags: gdp

I'm asking this question, since it was not explained in my textbook and since I couldn't find the answer in Internet. For example, 1 TB HDD costs 50 dollars now, and 100 GB HDD costed 50 dollars in year X. They are the same products but have different performances. Is the difference of performance neglected for real GDP?

Comment: Tricky subject. See Jorgenson, "Accounting for Growth in the Information Age" http://down.cenet.org.cn/upfile/34/200568201944107.pdf